# Unfixed element on top of RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".ui.base.core.example">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/topicsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_topics" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run this, the TextView element is fixed and scrolls when I scroll through my RecyclerView. Is there a way so that I can make it where the TextView element is on top of the RecyclerView and when I scroll it's not fixed? I'm using a TextView to just do testing, but eventually I'd like to have a header on top of the RecyclerView that shouldn't be scrollable with the RecyclerView and just stay on top.

Comment: It's honestly not clear what you want - you're saying the `TextView` is *fixed* but also *scrolls*, then you ask if there's a way to make it *scroll* and *not fixed*, and eventually you want it to be *fixed* and *not scroll*. What you have right now is fixed to the top of the layout, it won't scroll because it's not inside the `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView` is *on top of it* because that's also fixed to the top of the layout - Aleksey's answer fixes that

Comment: If you want it to scroll with your list, so it's above the first item, it'll have to be part of the recycler (where it actually is the first item!). If this layout is inside a `NestedScrollView` in another layout, then the `TextView` will scroll along with everything else (since you're basically looking through a window and moving this layout up and down behind it) and if you don't want that, you'd have to move the `TextView` out of the scrolling section

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up constraints.

Approximately like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/topicsRecyclerView" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/topicsRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

[image: img]

Comment: This covers the entire page with the textview

Comment: @user2896120 it should work fine if the `ConstraintLayout`'s height is set to `match_parent` - the `TextView`'s height here is `wrap_content` so it can't fill the screen (the one in your example does though, because it's set to `match_parent`)

Comment: I copied exactly what you have and still doesn't do what it should

Comment: I think it maybe because you have both the width and height set to 0dp for the recyclerview

Comment: You don't just need to copy. You need to take the constraints settings and apply them to your code. Added a picture of what it looks like.

Comment: The TextView stays in place, glued to the top of the screen. Its height is given by its content. The RecyclerView scrolls without changing the TextView. Its height is from the bottom of the TextView to the bottom of the screen.